# regexp of a modsec rule

Tags: mod-security

Is there a place I can view modsec rules?

Trying to save some javascipt & html code through elementor on wordpress triggered some modsec rule. Specifically:

`[file "/etc/apache2/conf.d/modsec/modsec/11_asl_adv_rules.conf"] [line "117"] [id "331028"] [rev "13"] [msg "Atomicorp.com WAF Rules:  Unauthorized SQL access to database Detected."]`

I want to see what in my html&JS triggered this rule, but the log I was sent from the hosting company only lists part of the regular expression (and I do not have access to said file).

Is the above list available anywhere? or can someone tell me what the full regexp is for this rule?

Comment: Have you searched for `11_asl_adv_rules.conf`?

Comment: Do you mean on the machine? I do not have access to it, its a hosted site. 
If you mean google, then yes I have and was not able to find what I was looking for.

Comment: If the hostong company won't give it to you, then you need to get the rule from Atomicorp.

Comment: @ schroeder please add this as an answer. I did get it from the hosting company and was able to resolve my issue.